# Executing related os commands in python

Tags: python, linux, shell, command, subprocess

I'm trying to create a simple script in python which is essentially a shell terminal. It will repeatedly ask for input commands and will attempt to execute the given os commands. What I cannot figure out, is how to make Python 'remember' the commands that were executed.

Example of what I mean:

1. User inputs `ls`
2. Python prints contents of current directory
3. Next user inputs `cd exampledir`
4. Python executes the command
5. User inputs `ls`
6. Python prints contents of `exampledir`

Since the command sequence is `ls` > `cd exampledir` > `ls` I expect the program to return the contents of the exampledir, but instead the output of the two `ls` commands is the same.

Is there a way to make Python somehow 'remember' the commands that were executed and execute next command based on the previous ones?

I know you can use something like `cd exampledir && ls` but this is not what I'm looking for. The commands must be executed separately like in a shell terminal.

Code so far:

```
import subprocess

while True:
    cmd = input("Command to Execute: ")
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    out = p.communicate()[0]
    print(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

you cant `cd` out with the `subprocess` module, the function will run but the path wont change for the python script that is running,
what you can do instead is something like:

```
import os
if # condition where cd command used:
  os.chdir("path/to/new/dir")
```

this will change the path for the python script that you're running and then you can `ls` to get a different output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The point of this project is to create a web application where a user can enter os commands (like in a terminal), these commands will get send to the server, get executed and return the output back to the web app. I'm looking for some generic way of doing this 'command chaining'. Like the command could be anything from 'ls' to 'grep' to 'scp'. The user should be able to execute commands as if they were using the servers actual terminal.

So do you know of any way I could create like a shell session where the result of each command would be remembered?

Comment: Ok , but you'll still have to check and filter all commands (somewhat like above), you cant just allow inputs as it is, that's dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you have to understand is: you want to write a **full** interpreter of shell commands. That means: any command that alters the **state** of your **shell** ... needs to well, change some internal state.

Meaning: your python "interpreter" starts within a certain directory. So when you tell the interpreter to **change** the directory, it can't just send that request to some shell that goes away one second later.

In other words: you can't have it both ways. Either you pass down **all** commands into a sub process; leading to the problem that makes up your question. Or your "interpreter" does "all the work" itself.

And just for the record: as you might have guessed - writing a "shell" is a complex task. What makes you think that you should re-invent that wheel?

Comment: Essentially what I am trying to build is a server monitoring web application. this app will monitor server resources (cpu, memory etc) and will also allow a user to launch a terminal emulator. This terminal emulator will accept shell commands from the user and will send them over WebSocket to the server where Python will execute them. and return the output over WebSocket to the user. I'm trying to figure out if something like this is even possible to do.